# Where/What do I code when I see "Error, Access Denied" when creating a bucket?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, machine-learning, access-denied, buckets

I am new to using AWS (and S.O.), and I am following the tutorial for Machine Learning, where it asks you to create a bucket. However, it keeps saying "Error Access Denied" when I am trying to create the bucket, lets me fill out some properties, and still says Access Denied. I have researched this question carefully and for quite a while, with many suggestions saying to correct the code for "Sid","Action","Effect","Allow", etc. However, I do not understand if this is my problem, and if it is, WHERE to write this code? I will show some screenshots of my screen that it shows me, and I opened up a file that shows code related to buckets. Thank you so much and I will be reading every answer carefully, I apologize
[Screenshot of my screen when attempting to create bucket](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FeZix.png)

[List of files when i clicked on this file named "alphaindex.h"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/56Nwx.png)

Comment: If you're getting access denied in the console, than the IAM user you're logged in with does not have permission to do whatever it is you're doing when you get access denied (presumably creating the bucket).

Comment: Okay so Im assuming my boss's has not granted me access then. thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The likely answer to why you can't create a bucket is that your IAM user does not have the appropriate permission to do so.  Whomever controls your account can add it to your IAM user.

I would suggest at minimum the following:

s3:CreateBucket
s3:ListAllMyBuckets
s3:PutObject
s3:GetObject
s3:DeleteObject

Though I can't guarantee that those are sufficient to do what you're trying to do.

Alternatively, you can be granted unlimited access to a specific bucket created for you.  Instructions for doing so are here:

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/writing-iam-policies-grant-access-to-user-specific-folders-in-an-amazon-s3-bucket/